# Calculate the date difference

Tags: excel, vba

Setting up sales invoices that I have for different customers does not follow any rules or regulations. I would like to prepare a report in which it is clear that each customer settles his debt in a few days. I have attached a file, but it is not suitable. Help me please. I also told many Iranian professors, but none of them succeeded. I'm from Iran. I'm sorry if my writing is incomplete.
Thanks
[sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bO-l34YXqrMJwhQd0PfEVb1p8GHvS-_O/view?usp=sharing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3XkX.png)

Comment: Hi Farhad. It's not at all clear what you are trying to do or where, specifically, you are stuck and unable to proceed. Please update your post with a specific question so we can help you.

Comment: Hello again
I have attached an example file to Excel

Comment: @FarhadBayaty I have looked at your example file but it is not clear to me what results you are expecting.   I recommend that you put some sample values in column H with a description of why they are correct or incorrect results.

Comment: More details are in the file
Please help me
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KxFFMLQtsDX3F4GkNCFPSlwp3YSXGDvM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hi
please check this page :
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/fifo-sell-excel-macro.44013/